# Find a document via mongo-driver golang with nested array

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I'm trying to do a basic query that searches for a document where a specific value is inside an array.
Lets take the following example:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "tenant": [
      "tenant1",
      "tenant2",
      "tenant3"
    ]
  }
}

filter := bson.M{"metadata": bson.M{"tenant": "tenant1"}}

collection := mongo.Database(DB).Collection(Collection)
result := collection.FindOne(context.Background(), filter)
```

The result here is empty, I tried working with $elemmatch it also didn't work.
when I take the array out of metadata it works.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `filter` filters for documents that has a `metadata` field that's a document with a `tenant` field with `tenant1` value.

To find documents that have a `metadata` field being a document, having a `tenant` array including the `tenant1` element, concatenate the field names with a dot:

```
filter := bson.M{"metadata.tenant": "tenant1"}
```

Comment: amazing, thanks!